# No data sources are configured to run this SQL

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea

I have a little problem with the creation of a table (for a database) in Java.

Currently, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and when I write the code for creating a table the text is highlighted in yellow and when I look to the problem I see the following message:

**"No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu (⌥⏎)."**

I tried with changing the SQL dialect (because before there was also that message that appeared) without result.

What should I do? I wrote something wrong in the code but I don't know why whit other example work perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
public static void createTable(){

    //connect to database
    String url = percorsoDatabase;

    //Statement create new table
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tabella (id PRIMARY KEY," +
            "video TEXT," +
            "game TEXT," +
            "firstAction TEXT," +
            "secondAction TEXT," +
            "thirdAction TEXT);";

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e ){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I've already create a SQLite database and established a connection that works (before that), here's the code if it could be useful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    createNewDatabase();
    connection();
    createTable();
}

public static void createNewDatabase(){

    String url = percorsoDatabase;

    Connection conn;
    try {

     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        if (conn != null){
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("The driver name is" + meta.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("A new database has been created.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public static void connection(){

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //String url = "jdbc:sqlite://Volumes/Isma/Documenti/SUPSI/APA/Stage/"
        //        + "Beans/esperimento/dati.db";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(percorsoDatabase);
        System.out.println("Connection to SQLite established.");
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null){
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

So... If you can help me I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance for the answer and have a nice day!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This warning indicates that you have not configured data source in Database Tool Window in Intellij Idea. It doesn't mean that your code is wrong, it just shows that you don't have code completion based on your database schema.

Configuration of datasource in Intellij is described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html

Comment: Ahh ok. Thank you very much! That's what I was searching.

Answer (score 40):

The message:

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance.

is a little explicit and IMHO a little unnecessary, because I really think that I don't need to configure a database for every project in which we have some SQL queries.

To handle this message, you have two options:

1. Configure a **Data Source** to your project, using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> above the message and using the option *Configure a Data Source*:
   [image: Add a data source]

or

2. Disable this *SQL dialect detection* inspection on the Inspection options on the IDE settings:

[image: Disable the SQL dialect detection]

You may need to disable as well **No data sources configured** inspection on:

`Inspections -> SQL -> No data sources configured`

The second option is the best approach for me unless you really want or need a Data Source in your project.

Comment: Actually these days you need to disable as well Inspections -> SQL -> No data sources configured

Comment: This should be an answer

Answer (score 5):

The IntelliJ Idea is an intelligent IDE, and sometimes need some configurations that can help you soon.

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced
> code assistance

The above-mentioned warning will never affect your application and you can easily skip it, but by setting the data source you can take advantage of IntelliJ's [Database tools and SQL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/relational-databases.html)﻿ outstanding features.

To set the data-source follow View Tools Window Database and then click the Data Source Properties button. In the shown window select your database and fill in the required text fields.

The demonstration of steps are shown in the following GIF:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the connection to your database.

```
url - a database url of the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname
```

Check the Api 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)

Did you add the ODBC correct?

Answer (score 0):

I disable the *no data sources configured*, and I set a *ignore* option, no warning shows up.
setting -> Inspections -> no data sources configured -> +

[pycharm setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zg3x.png)