# php update query always go to else

Tags: php, function, sql-update

I am trying to update database with php update function but it always goes to else

It seems to me the no syntax error

```
function UpdateData()
{
    $bookid = textboxValue("book_id");
    $bookname = textboxValue("book_name");
    $bookpublisher = textboxValue("book_publisher");
    $bookprice = textboxValue("book_price");

    if($bookname&&$bookpublisher&&$bookpublisher){

        $sql="UPDATE books SET book_name='$bookname', book_publisher='$bookpublisher', book_price='$bookprice' WHERE id='$bookid' ";
        if(mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql)){
            TextNode("success",'data successfully update');
        }else{
            TextNode("error","enable to update data");
        }
    }else{
        TextNode("error","select data using edit icon");
    }
}
```

Error:

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL

Comment: That sounds like an error from an IDE, not from running the code

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: If a query does not work as you think it should, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) in your else. This will tell you exactly what is wrong with your query instead of trying to make a guess.

Comment: @aynber, thanks for your reply. can you be more specific?

Comment: Which part? The links I posted will help you in adjusting your code to check for errors and preventing quoting issues.

Comment: @aynber, I am using PHP storm.

Comment: check that your connection to DB is correctly created or not. For that just try to run a select query and check the results.

Comment: @aynber,mysqli errors, thanks,Jacky

Comment: I figured that you were using PHPStorm, considering the "no data sources". That's just a warning that means that it can't check the syntax for your sql, so you can ignore that message.

Comment: @anujarora. connect db is correct. Create and Read function works well, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No data sources are configured to run this SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933570/no-data-sources-are-configured-to-run-this-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Your error "No data sources are configured to run this SQL" is an IDE specific error for PHPStorm **not** for *your code* syntax.

"Live" code errors will be found in your [PHP error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel).

You can find guidance from JetBrains for setting up your SQL analysis for PHPStorm [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html).

You may also get help on this topic here: [No data sources are configured to run this SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933570/no-data-sources-are-configured-to-run-this-sql)

Comment: @all, thanks to you all for the help. I finally figured it out. In the if condition I have 3 input fields. I need to enter all the input field otherwise it goes to "else". I am closing this question. Again, thanks to you all and have a good day! Jacky

Comment: @NewProgrammer that `if` condition does not relate to the error you put in your question.